# "No routes found" on Google Maps first launch

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I want to launch Google Maps from my application to navigate from my location to an address with the following code :

```
NSString *myAddress = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"comgooglemaps://?daddr=Paris,France"] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myAddress]];
```

When that code is executed if google maps is not already open in background it displays "No routes location" else it find a route.
In the two cases I have same starting ("My location" by default) and ending points.
No problem if I specify a starting point, for example :

```
NSString *myAddress = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"comgooglemaps://?saddr=Cannes,France&daddr=Paris,France"] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding];
```

Is there any solution to fix that issue ?

Answer (score 1):

checkout this link , may be it will help . 
      [google map developer ios](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme)

for getting direction from your current location.
  1- first get your current location with location manager . 
  2- add it in url as saddr  //this what you are doing in second line(static start address)
  3- then add your destination

try this

```
NSString *location=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f",self.locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude.latitude,self.locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude.longitude];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:
     [NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps://"]]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:
     //[NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps://?center=40.765819,-73.975866&zoom=14&views=traffic"]];
     [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"comgooglemaps://?saddr=&daddr=%@&directionsmode=%@&views=satellite",location,mode]]
     ];
} else {

    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Google Map app not found \n please install it." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Install", nil] show];
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have already read that link and try with others parameters like directionsmode=driving but with the same result.

Comment: Works if I specify a starting point but I prefer to use default "My location" of Google Maps. I think I will just call following url : "comgooglemaps://?q=Paris, France", users will just have to click on navigate button.
Thanks for your help

Comment: I think there is just an error in your url String : 
[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"comgooglemaps://?saddr=%@&daddr=%@&directionsmode=%@&views=satellite",location, destination,mode]]

Comment: it because i had copied it from my code. dont worry its working at my end.